# Trying to make an un-ordered list in php

Tags: php, html, text

I'm very new to php and I am trying to write a small application that reads a text file and makes it into an un-ordered list. My goal is to make the text file more readable, so I want to make the headers bold, and simply make the listed items have little markers by them (like they should if they are in an un-ordered list). I wrote the php to do this, but it is not doing what I expected. Instead, it takes each line and makes it bigger and bigger font until it gets so big its unreadable. I cannot see what I am doing wrong here. Does anyone see something that I am missing or have written incorrectly? Below I have pasted the original text file and my php code respectively. Thanks in advance for your help and patience with my limited php knowledge.

```
Best Picture
American Hustle
Captain Phillips
Dallas Buyers Club
Gravity
Her
Nebraska
Philomena
12 Years a Slave
The Wolf of Wall Street

Best Actor
Christian Bale (American Hustle)
Bruce Dern (Nebraska)
Leonardo DiCaprio (The Wolf of Wall Street)
Chiwetel Ejiofor (12 Years a Slave)
Matthew McConaughey (Dallas Buyers Club)

Best Actress
Amy Adams (American Hustle)
Cate Blanchett (Blue Jasmine)
Sandra Bullock (Gravity)
Judi Dench (Philomena)
Meryl Streep (August: Osage County)
```

** The 3 headers are supposed to be best picture, best actor, and best actress.

** Below is my php code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Un-ordered List</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$file = fopen("oscars.txt", "r");
$i=0;
while(!feof($file))
{
$members[]= fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
$arrlength =count($members);
$title = True;
echo $members;
for($i=0;$i<($arrlength);$i++)
{
    if($title=True)
    {
        echo "<h2>" . $members[$i] . "<h2><ul>";
        $title = False;
    }
    if(trim($members[$i])=='')
    {
        echo "</ul><h2>" . $members[$i+1] . "</h2><ul>";
        $i++;
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo "<li>" . $members[$i] . "</li>" ;
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: stop using text files and start using a data base

Comment: `=` should be `==` in `if($title=true)`

Comment: == did a lot to fix it. The entire first list though is still  bold

Comment: you don't properly close your first `<h2>`

Comment: that's because the second `<h2>` should be `</h2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `=` into `==` in the `if`. And change the second `<h2>` into `</h2>`.

But for compactness, consider this code:

```
echo "<html><head><title>Un-ordered List</title></head><body>";
foreach( array_map("htmlspecialchars", file("oscars.txt")) as $line ) {
  if (!isset($flag)) {
    $flag = true;
    echo "<h2>{$line}</h2><ul>";
  } else {
    echo "<li>{$line}</li>";
  }
}
if (isset($flag)) {
  echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have become more confident with PHP, I recommend reading up on MySQL and databases, because it will be more suited to this kind of data storage. However, I have managed to come up with a solution to your problem, but it involves adding an asterisk (*) to the beginning of each heading in the text file. This is so the code can determine which lines are headings and which aren't.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Un-ordered List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $members = file("oscars.txt"); // load file into array

        foreach($members as $member) // assign each object in the array to $members on each iteration
        {
            $member = trim($member); // perhaps unnecessary, but good practise

            if(substr($member, 0, 1) == '*') // if there is an asterisk, it is a header
            {
                echo "<h2>" . substr($member, 1, strlen($member)) . "</h2>"; // print the heading, minus the asterisk
            }
            else if ($member !== '') // don't print blank lines
            {
                echo "<li>" . $member . "</li>"; // not a heading, so print as a list element
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have almost entirely rewritten the code but I feel that some of the things you had written were unnecessary, such as using `$arrlength =count($members)` when a `foreach` loop is better suited to the job. It will take each string from the `$members` array and then output it in place of the `$member` variable.

I have also changed some formatting, but that is not important.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Un-ordered List</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$file = fopen("oscars.txt", "r");

$i=1;
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    if(strlen(trim($line)) == 0){ 
        print "</ul>";
        $i=0;
    }  

    if ($i !=0){
        if ($i==1) print "<b>".$line."</b>";
        else {
            if ($i==2) print "<ul><li>".$line."</li>";
            else print "<li>".$line."</li>";
        }
    }

    $i++;   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

**Best Picture**

- American Hustle
- Captain Phillips
- Dallas Buyers Club
- Gravity
- Her
- Nebraska
- Philomena
- 12 Years a Slave
- The Wolf of Wall Street

**Best Actor**

- Christian Bale (American Hustle)
- Bruce Dern (Nebraska)
- Leonardo DiCaprio (The Wolf of Wall Street)
- Chiwetel Ejiofor (12 Years a Slave)
- Matthew McConaughey (Dallas Buyers Club)

**Best Actress**

- Amy Adams (American Hustle)
- Cate Blanchett (Blue Jasmine)
- Sandra Bullock (Gravity)
- Judi Dench (Philomena)
- Meryl Streep (August: Osage County)